# Word for intense love for the color black

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call someone with intense love for the color black?

Comment: I think it's *extremely* unlikely there would be a single-word term or common expression for such a person, outside of highly offensive references where "black" is being used to denote "dark-skinned, negroid", for the skin colour of *people* (I hesitate to even mention over 6000 written instances of [***ni##er-loving***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22nigger-loving%22), for example). But even if there were such a term that in theory should be a reference to someone's preferred colour in other contexts, it would be likely to be misused, so I doubt you should use it anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  If we have Melanophobia for the fear of the color black, why wouldn't we have a corresponding -philia for the love of it?

Comment: [***Melanophobia,** or fear of the black, may be pragmatically as valuable a racial defence for the white as the counter-instinct of **philoleucosis***.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Melanophobia%2C+or+fear+of+the+black%22) To my mind the mere fact that anyone should want to have specific "words" for such aberrant ways of thinking is a sad reflection of shallow and insensitive thinking (I also don't like "**the** black" in that cite). Neither of them are in the full OED anyway, but so far as I'm concerned they're just dog-whistles for pseudoscientific racism.

Comment: Some people love wearing black because it is dark and evokes night and melancholy and evil; some love it because they don't have to colour-coordinate or think what to wear, and it looks smart.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a person who presents herself as '*addicted to black*':

https://ravishly.com/2015/05/01/how-do-i-get-over-my-addiction-black

Answer (score 1):

https://www.2knowmyself.com/Why_some_people_only_wear_black 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wednesday_Addams
i think ::: ***"Wednesday Addams"***

Not any specific thing that I know of. There are many different types of people that wear black all the time. Some are called Goths which is short for Gothic people, but others just like to wear black all the time. Everyone in the 80’s wore black all the time, especially in NYC and LA and SF.

Witches tend to wear black all the time and that is why they have black cats, because if they had white cats, the cat fur would show up on their clothing and look bad and messy.

With black cats, you don’t see their fur on black clothing and it also saves a lot of money on lint rollers, which was especially convenient during the heyday of witches in centuries earlier, especially considering that lint rollers had not yet been invented and would not be for hundreds of years; and only the richest and most powerful of witches had access to time machines to travel into the future to go to Target or Walmart and buy these lint removers.

So remember, whatever you choose to call yourself, if you are going to wear black all the time, it is smartest to own only black cats or dogs etc.

And it also helps out those black cats and dogs because unfortunately many people are prejudiced against black cats and dogs and will not adopt them and so many of them get euthanized for just being black or they have to stay at the shelters for a really long time.

When I got one of my black cats, she had been at the shelter for over 4 months. I told the people at the shelter that I would just take the cat that had been there longest and that was she. Her name was Stella and she was a great cat.

So wear black all the time and call yourself whatever you want and help out and adopt black cats and dogs. Contrary to superstition they make great and friendly pets